# Translation of a text with an object within it

Tags: asp.net, translate

I translated my application via the method with App_GlobalResources and .resx files. It's ok, but only on one point: I have a datagrid in hyperlinkcolumn that the text has an image, that is:

```
Text="&lt;img title='View target location on map' border='no' src='immagini/icone/mappa.png' /&gt;"
```

and I would translate the title so that the mouse over the image to the passage I have a tooltip; I tried to enter the field `"<%$ Resources:MyPage, ValueTitle %>"`, but does not work ....
You can translate it?
Thanks for the reply..

dave

Answer (score 0):

I did it using jquery in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var test = '<%=GetGlobalResourceObject(MyPage, TitleValue)%>'
                $("#GrdRisultatoRicerca td:nth-child(8) > a").append(
                    $('<img />').attr("title",test).attr("border","no").attr("src" ,"immagini/icone/Parcheggio.gif"));
 });
```

Maybe I think it is fine ....